# colobox popup redirect to blank page When click on link

Tags: drupal-7, colorbox

I have use colorbox-node module to show modal window. Add the following code in block:

```
echo $links ='<a class="colorbox-node" href="http://example.com/my_day_modal?width=600&height=600">My Day Modal</a>';
```

When I click on link the popup opens but its not show any data and redirect to blank page. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? and How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!